# How can I have a wcf service use my asp.net request/response filter?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap, wse

I have an older soap web service using microsoft's WSE library.  It's now not supported in our target .net framework and operating system.  I have converted the service to use wcf on the server but the client will still use the old web-service proxy.  The problem I am currently having is that the client compress the http request to save us bandwidth.  In The asp.net application I have a httpmodual that detects if the client sent use a gzip/deflate based on the content-encoding of the request header.  Now that the service is wcf it does not read from the asp.net request stream and the decompression is not working.  Clients that do not compress the request do currently work.  How could I make the wcf service integrate with the asp.net pipeline?

Comment: Is the WCF service running in IIS? If so, can you enable Http Compression in IIS for the server?

Comment: the wcf service is running under iis.  Will the Http Compression work in win2003-win2012?  and will it handle compressed requests?

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual to compress HTTP *requests*.  See https://serverfault.com/q/56700, Apache has some support for it, but I'm pretty sure ASP.NET/IIS does not have any native support.  So you'll have to accept the stream in raw form and decode it yourself.